# WebAPI does not initialize?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, react-redux

I have a WebAPI project that is included as a dependency to a frontend React+Redux project.

I created a code first database with a controller exposing some HttpGet functions where the functions modify a DbContext database.

When the app runs the Startup.ConfigureServices is not called and the webapi calls from React gets me this error:

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

WebAPI functions from a different controller which don't use DBcontext stuff work though..

In LinkController I have the following:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LinkController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public URLSubmitResult SubmitLink(string url)
    {
        return new URLSubmitResult() { Success = true };
    }

    public class URLSubmitResult
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
    }
 }

  private readonly LinkDbContext _context;

  public LinkController(LinkDbContext context)
  {
     _context = context;
  }
```

In ValuesController the following:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public URLSubmitResult SubmitLink(string url)
    {
        return new URLSubmitResult() { Success = true };
    }

    public class URLSubmitResult
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
    }

    public ValuesController()
    {

    }
```

The call is not happening if I go api/link/submitlink?url=lol.com but it does if it's api/values/submitlink?url=lol.com

The actual issue, regardless of the error I'm receiving in the response, is that api/link/submit link is not resulting in the controller function being called. 
Most likely scenario is an undefined result is coming back which isn't typecasting to json.

Comment: Where is this error happening? Most probably it is some problem with the data you are trying to pass to api function.

Comment: Probably you are sending it formatted as Xml and Web Api is trying to deserialize as Json

Comment: nah it's not that, as I said a similar call (with string parameter)  to another controller that doesn't rely on dbcontext works fine, the initialization functions are not being called for the dbcontext dependent controller.

Comment: I don't see how dbcontext could affect deserialization. It seems coincidence. The error states clearly that the first token of the content is <.  As Pedro mentioned, you are probably sending Xml. Use Fiddler to verify this. The difference may be in the client code. Perhaps you use PostAsJsonAsync for the first controller and PostAsync for the second.

Comment: As I mentioned the calls and their body are alike between the two controllers, and regardless what happens in the response the webapi function itself is not called in one of the controllers. Any problem in the response body in React is a follow on from the fact the WebApi function wasn't called so it's a red herring to try and chase down.

I've edited my question to make this more clear since people clearly don't believe me.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question. The combination of Unexpected token < and the comments lead me to believe that the problem was in the request itself. But now I understand that this is the response message.

Answer (score 0):

So basically the issue was that the referenced WebAPI assembly was not adding the appropriate service to the Dependency injection.

In Startup.ConfigureServices for the main project I added:

```
 services.AddDbContext<LinkDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LinkDBConnectionString")));
```

Along with the connection string (LinkDBConnectionString) the dependency injection worked and the WebAPI initialized.

From some more experience I've found this project setup is not really what I want which was to decouple the frontend from the WebAPI, including the WebAPI as a dependency to the frontend is not the answer in the case of web.

Instead I now run the WebAPI as its own thing in Visual Studio and do calls to it through the frontend.